# greater/less than signs are not escaped

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am trying to escape strings in server side (Node.js & Express.js) which contains greater/less than signs (<, >) and i use this code on server side

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {
   data.message = data.message.replace(/\</g,"&lt;")   //for <
   data.message = data.message.replace(/\>/g,"&gt;")   //for >   
   io.in(socket.current_room).emit('message',{message :data.message, id: socket.id});
});
```

and on client side (inside `socket.on('message')` function)

```
output.innerHTML += `<div class="mymessage-container"><div class="mymessage"><p class="me">` + message + '</p></div></div>'
```

it replaces the signs but it displays them as replaced, for example: user send message: `<hello>`, message will displayeed as `&lt;hello&gt;`.
How can i fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a second `replace` on the client side - and you're using template literals so you can use the `${}` pattern:

```
output.innerHTML += `<div class="mymessage-container"><div class="mymessage"><p class="me">${message.replace(/\&lt\;/g, "<").replace(/\&gt\;/g, ">")}</p></div></div>`
```

Comment: it displays nothing

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `&lt;hello&gt;` is because of data.message.replace the second argument you passed is the string that will take place for the one that was found.

You can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) an explanation on what replace does.

If you want it blank you can do this `data.message = data.message.replace(/\</g,"")`.

Sidenote: You don't need to add the backslash before < or > because is not a special character. This works fine for me `data.message.replace(/</g,"")`.

Comment: Thank you but this is practical, not professional way.

Comment: Don't really get what you mean with not a professional way but hope it helps.

Comment: I mean that user must be able to send what s/he wants, thank you for your answer but at this point blocking everything that causes problems is not good choice for me i prefer to fix them

Comment: You can pass whatever you want inside and it works fine so it fixes it. You might want to elaborate a bit more on how you need help.